# how to change the ffmpeg buffer for input video

Tags: ffmpeg, buffer-overflow

**How to change this buffer that is still 3M**

Current launch command:

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -vcodec libx264 -preset:v ultrafast -filter:v "crop=480:270:0:0" -vf tpad=start_duration=30 -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 1G -maxrate 2500k -bufsize 1G -rtbufsize 1G -sws_flags lanczos+accurate_rnd -acodec aac -b:a 96k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/test

For our final setup we would like to have 140 seconds of delay added to this stream.

We're setting:
-bufsize 1G
-rtbufsize 1G
-b:v 1G
to set all of our buffers to 1G, but it seems that it has a different buffer that I cannot seem to find that is set to around 3M
[image: Bufferoverflow]

[image: CMD Capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `-rtbufsize` but it is meant to be applied to an input so it goes before that input.

So, your command would start as `ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 1G -i video="screen-capture-recorder"`

Comment: That seems to work, but it seems to fill up that buffer and a 2gig buffer within 1/2 second. I guess one would need compression for this to work then?

Comment: Your input is 2560x1440 32 bits per pixel at 30 fps. Which is 420 MB/s. And you wish to hold onto 30 seconds of data before processing it. You'll need plenty of RAM. There may be a way to cache it on disk but I'll have to test that.